# Exact Sequence of commutative Lie-groups induces exact sequence of connected components

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, schemes

I am working on commutative Lie-groups and I am not so sure about the following problem.
Suppose we have an exact sequence of commutative Lie-groups
$1 \rightarrow A \rightarrow B \rightarrow C \rightarrow 1$ and denote with $(-)^0$ the connected component to the identity of the Lie-groups. Suppose that $A$, $B$ and $C$ have finely many connected components. Hence by a theorem, which is called "Open Mapping Theorem" (11.1.8) in Neeb, Hilgert "Structure and geometry of Lie-Groups" the induced morphism of the Lie-algebras of $B$ and $C$ is surjective. Hence we have a surjective Lie-group homomorphism
$B^0 \rightarrow C^0\rightarrow 1$. Now I would like to look at this kernel and hopefully it is connected. Does anybody know, if this is true? Do we maybe have the identity $im(A^0)=B^0$?

Thanks for any comment

Added version:

What I really want to show is the following:

Let $k=\mathbb{C}$ or $\mathbb{R}$. Let. $X/k$ be a smooth commutative group scheme of finite type and $A/k$ an abelian variety. Suppose we have an exact sequence of commutative Lie-groups
$0 \rightarrow k^\star \rightarrow X(k) \overset{\beta}{\rightarrow} A(k) \rightarrow 0$.

I want to show, that (if we denote again with $(-)^0$ the identity) component, that $\beta(X(k)_{max.komp.})\subset A(k)^0$ holds. I tried that using a theorem, which states if we have an exact sequence of commutative connected Lie-groups, we obtain an exact sequence of the maximal compact subgroups, which uses the representation of a connected  compact Lie-group. Thats why I wanted to reduce to the case of the identity components, but this sequence is not exact anymore I think.

Again: Edited :D

Sorry, I realize I should really learn more about that :D So I reduced the problem to the following:

Assume we have a surjective Lie-grouphomomorphism of abelian Lie-groups $G \rightarrow H$ and the corresponding Lie-algebra homomorphism $L(G)\rightarrow L(H)$ is surjective too. What I want to show is, that then the Lie-algebra homomorphism $L(G_{max.compact})\rightarrow L(H)$ is surjective too, again $G_{max.compact}$ is the maximal compact subgroup of $G$. Maybe this is because $G_{max.compact}$ is the maximal compact subgroup? Does anyone know, why if is true?

Thanks for you're help!

Comment: What if $B = C = S^1$ and the map is $z\mapsto z^2$?  Then the kernel is $\{\pm 1\}$, which is disconnected, but $B$ and $C$ are already connected.

Comment: Yes you're right!

Comment: So maybe we can use another argument. What I really want to show is, that the induced map $(B^0)_{max.comp.}\rightarrow (C^0)_{max.comp.}$ is surjective. To be a little bit more precise, $A=k\star$, where $k=\mathbb{C}$ or $k=\mathbb{R}$. If one has an exact sequence of connected Lie-groups, this is known. In this situation it is not so sure. Maybe we need, that the exponential of $k \rightarrow k^\star$ is surjective? Thanks for you're help.

Comment: What do you mean by "max.comp"?  Also, if you want me to be notified of your comment, you can write @jasondevito somewhere in it.

Comment: @JasonDeVito thanks for that comment. I mean the maximal compact subgroup

Comment: Oh, I was thinking "comp" was component.  I forgot that non-compact Lie groups exist!  I believe it is true that the map you care about is surjective (after appropriately conjugating the codomain).  I'll try to write up an answer if I can think of a proof.

Comment: Actually, on second thought, I don't think it's true.  If $B = \mathbb{R}$ and $C = S^1$, then with the map $B\rightarrow C$ given by the covering, then this map is surjective, but the maximal compact in $\mathbb{R}$ is finite, so can't map onto $C$.

Comment: @JasonDeVitofirst of all many thanks for you're comments. I added my question to be a little more precise. So what "must be true" (the paper says it), is, that $\beta(X(k)_{max.compact})\subset A(k)^0$ and I am trying to find the answer for that. They say, that this follows from the existence of an exponential.

Comment: I'm afraid I know nothing about schemes, so someone else will have to help now.  Sorry!

Comment: @JasonDeVitoto be honest, I don't think, this has something to do with schemes :D So we can view $X(k)$ ask $A(k)$ as commutative Lie-groups and also we know, that $A(k)$ is compact. Also we know, that $X(k)$ and also $A(k)$ have only finely many connected components.

Comment: One last try from me, then I need to get back to my own work ;-).  What if $k = \mathbb{R}$, $X = S^1\times \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \times\mathbb{R}^\ast$, and $A = S^1\times \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ with $\beta(z,\pm 1, r) = (z, \pm 1)$.  Then the kernel is $\mathbb{R}^\ast$, $\beta$ is surjective, but $max comp (X)$ contains $S^1\times \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, which does not map into the identity component of $S^1\times \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @JasonDeVito you're right, this was silly. I now reduced the problem again (see my edited post). This seems easy for one who knows some stuff about Lie-groups. Maybe do you have an idea? :)

Comment: As to your last question, this is still false, using the covering $\mathbb{R}\rightarrow S^1$.